# Notation for vector fields on cotangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

This is probably an easy question. I have some trouble finding the right notation/words for 2 vector fields.

Consider $T^*S^1$, the cotangent bundle of the circle. I know that this is a trivial vector bundle, so $T^*S^1 \simeq S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$. How do I formally introduce the vector fields on $T^* S^1$ that "goes around the loop" and the vector field that "goes along the cilinder"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any choice of coordinate chart $(U, \phi)$ on $\Bbb S^1$ (say, with coordinate $x$) determines a preferred coordinate chart $(\hat{U}, \hat{\phi})$ on $T^* \Bbb S^1$, where $$\hat{U} := \pi^{-1}(U) \quad \textrm{and} \quad \hat\phi(p, \alpha) := (\phi(p), q) \in \phi(U) \times \Bbb R ,$$ and where $\alpha = q \,dx$. (Here, $\pi$ is just the canonical projection $T^* \Bbb S^1 \to \Bbb S^1$ given by $(p, \alpha) \mapsto p$.) As indicated in the question, we can patch these charts together that give a *canonical* identification $T_1 \Bbb S^1 \stackrel{\approx}{\to} \Bbb S^1 \times \Bbb R$.

In the coordinates $(x, q)$, the vector field $\partial_q$ is vertical (i.e., tangent to the fibers, as $T_{(x, q)} \hat\pi \cdot \partial_q\vert_{(x, q)} = 0$ for all $(x, q) \in \hat U$) and the vector field $\partial_x$ is "orbital". If we choose $U$ to be an angular chart, then in the chart $(\hat U, \hat \phi)$, these agree with (under the appropriate identifications) the standard vector fields $\partial_q$ and $\partial_{\theta}$ on the factors $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb S^1$ of the above factorization.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had something like this in mind, but I thought that this way you only define $\partial_x$ on $\pi^{-1} (\phi(U))$ and that I had to show that $\partial_x$ agrees on the overlap of $\pi^{-1} (\phi(U))$ and $\pi^{-1} (\tau(V))$ for some other chart $(V,\tau)$ of $\mathbb{S}^1$

Comment: You have to show this if you want to construct *global* vector fields. Indeed, one needs to choose overlapping charts nicely to get a local vector fields that overlap appropriately, and there's a natural way to achieve this in this setting, namely but choosing the local charts to be ones that use (oriented) angular coordinates. I've tweaked the wording of my answer to indicate that this is really what we want. (And you're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful.)